# Android: Send information from App

Tags: java, android

I've developed an Android. Being my very first app, it's a silly one.

However, I want the app to send me the names entered by the user as an email, or upload them online, basically somewhere where I can access them. And this whole process should occur without letting the user know.
Hence, I would like to know how can I do all this?

Comment: Dude get a life , and develop a proper app

Comment: @NirajSanghani Yeah I will develop one for sure. But this is a fun thing. I want to love what I do. And I love fun and exciting things. This might act as a motivation